# Avalonia: Use default font of current OS

Tags: avalonia

I created a new Avalonia project without any changes and compiled for linux by using `dotnet publish -r linux-x64`. I'm still new to Avalonia, but shouldn't the default OS font be used? Is it possible to set the font to the default OS font?
In the screenshot you can see that the font doesn't match the other windows in Ubuntu (file explorer, calculator e.g.)
I also tried to get the actual font name that is used, but I always get the value $Default.

```
Avalonia.Media.FontManager.Current.DefaultFontFamily.Name
Avalonia.Media.FontFamily.DefaultFontFamilyName
```

[image]